# Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Exercise 19: Learn Python the Hard Way

Tags: python, python-2.6

The code below works as intended, but is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this?

If I don't change the raw_input into integers using int(), they're added like strings (ie. '10 + 10' = '1010').

Additionally, I can't seem to add int() onto the same line as the raw_input (ie.

`user_cheeses = raw_input("How many cheeses do you have?:\n> ").int()`

), for I get the error - 'str' object has no attribute 'int'.

```
def cheese_and_crackers(cheese_count, boxes_of_crackers):
    print "You have %r cheeses!" % cheese_count
    print "You have %r boxes of crackers!" % boxes_of_crackers
    print "Man that's enough for a party!"
    print "Get a blanket.\n"

print "We can put in inputs from you as well!:"
user_cheeses = raw_input("How many cheeses do you have?:\n> ")
user_cheeses_number = int(user_cheeses)

user_crackers = raw_input("How many boxes of crackers do you have?:\n >")
user_crackers_number = int(user_crackers)

cheese_and_crackers(user_cheeses, user_crackers)

print "You can also add even more cheeses and more crackers!:"
more_cheeses = raw_input("How many more cheeses do you now have?:\n> ")
more_cheeses_number = int(more_cheeses)

more_crackers = raw_input("How many more crackers do you now have?:\n> ")
more_crackers_number = int(more_crackers)

cheese_and_crackers(user_cheeses_number + more_cheeses_number, user_crackers_number + more_crackers_number)
```

Comment: As the code works, this question could be more on topic at [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int()` is not a method of strings. `int()` is a (built-in) *function*, so you need to apply it to the *result* of `raw_input()`:

```
user_cheeses = int(raw_input("How many cheeses do you have?:\n> "))
```

You do so indirectly by applying it to `user_cheeses` in your code:

```
user_cheeses_number = int(user_cheeses)
```

where `user_cheeeses` is the string that `raw_input()` returned.